# Is Razor related to .NET like LINQ is?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Anders Hejlsberg decribes LINQ as syntactic sugar.  In other words, it is still C#.  Just that they have added some shortcuts so you don't have to code everything by hand that LINQ is creating for you.  But the C# language and .NET runtime did not undergo any structural changes.

Is Razor the same way?

I'm not sure how it lines up when things are expressed as layers.  For example, is this correct?

```
Razor
 ^
ASP.NET
 ^
C#
 ^
.NET
```

I believe it is correct but I'm not sure how ASP.NET fits in.  Razor is ASP.NET right except that it adds a few syntactic extras or is it more than that?

What exactly is ASP.NET adding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Linq isn't just syntactic sugar.  The shorthand form of Linq in C# is, but you don't need that at all to use Linq.
2. Linq is a bunch of things.  It is a collection of extension methods over IEnumerable & IQueryable, it is lambdas and anonymous types and yield and a deferred execution pipeline.  Linq involves everything Microsoft added to .NET in Framework 3.5.
3. Razor is a template engine for rendering HTML.

Comment: Is the template engine part of ASP.NET or where does it come from?  It must tie into .NET some how right, since it is using C# syntax and so well integrated.

Comment: @4thSpace: It can use VB syntax too.  Neither one's a huge stretch, considering .net exposes VB and C# compilers as as part of the class library.

Comment: @4thSpace: Yes, it's part of ASP.NET.  You can use the same syntax with ASP.NET pages.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Cool.  Can you see this comment below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909045/is-razor-related-to-net-like-linq-is/16909064#comment24405061_16909064.  I think you are saying it is incorrect?

Comment: @4thSpace: Namespaces are namespaces.  It doesn't matter what DLL they live in.

Answer (score 3):

Your figure is sort of correct in terms of dependency graph. However It is best to think of razor as a template language for the web written in C#

In some ways the graph is in accurate. E.g C# does not really depend on .NET in general. You could write a non .NET runtime for C#.

Similarly Razor does not need to depend on ASP.NET. In fact its current implementation depends on classes found in ASP.NET MVC which only indirectly depends on ASP.NET conventional.

Saying Razor is to ASP.NET link Linq is to C# is a bit in accurate. Linq is a set of functions found in System.Linq namespace e.g. `Where` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx . C# provides a handy syntax to call these functions for you i.e http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

Razor however does not have such a clear seperation of syntax vs. backend function calls.

Comment: Is that like using the "dynamic" keyword but some how they've made it so you don't have to...and gave it a name?  I didn't understand your last statement.  Do you have a link explaining that?

Comment: `dynamic` was added in .NET Framework 4.0.  Linq predates it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not referring to LINQ.  I'm referring to Razor.

Comment: @4thSpace which last sentence :) I've been updating this answer :)

Comment: This one (you say it doesn't depend on asp.net but then you say it does): "Razor does not need to depend on ASP.NET. In fact its current implementation depends on classes found in ASP.NET MVC which only indirectly depends on ASP.NET conventional."

Comment: @4thSpace The conventional ASP.NET is in `system.web` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspx 

Razor is in `system.web.mvc` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc(v=vs.90).aspx

You could write `system.web.mvc` and hence razor without depending on Microsoft's ASP.NET

Comment: @BASarat Ok, I see what you are saying.  I just don't see how.  What renders razor code if asp.net is not there?

Comment: @4thSpace It is a View Engine. ASP.NET MVC hands over the request to classes found in `System.Web.Razor` Which parse the text (cshtml file) and generate executable .NET code : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor(v=vs.111).aspx